# How to get object properties if it's inside an array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the js object structure like this:

```
Object {
    name: "name";
    id: "id";
    subGroups_id : Array[1] 0: 9
}
```

I want to get the subGroup_id and turn into the name of the subgroup according to the id of the subGroup, I'm using `angularjs` and I'm doing this:

```
var users = angular.module('groups', ['app']);
users.controller('groupsCtrl', ['$scope', 'apiService', 'rpcService', function($scope, apiService){

    function getGroupsList() {
        $scope.groupsList = [];
        apiService.getGroups(0)
            .success(function (data) {
            $scope.groupsList = data;
            console.log($scope.groupsList);
        })
            .error(function (data, status, headers) {
        });
    };

    getGroupsList();
}]);
```

If you can explain me how to do this I would really appreciate it

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

assume the group name is in `groupsList`

`$scope.groupsList[yourObj.subGroups_id][0]`

--

```
yourObj.subGroups_id // Array[1] 0: 9
yourObj.subGroups_id[0] // 9
$scope.groupsList[9] // value at index 9 assuming it is group name
```

Comment: I'm connecting to an API, how can I change it dynamically to set this value according to the subGroups_ids